# Constructing object of generic class from string in Java

Tags: java, generics

Check out the following class:

```
public class Range<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    public T lower;
    public T upper;

    public Range(String range){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(range);
        if(scanner.hasNextInt())
            this.lower = scanner.nextInt();
        if(scanner.hasNextInt())
            this.upper = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public String toString(){
        return lower + " - " + upper;
    }
}
```

In constructor, I'm trying to construct an object from a string. Values that the creating object contain are in String range. The string has a format like a string that is return from toString method.

This won't work so easily, the error is on last two lines of constructor, and it says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to T." Ofcourse... Because the T type is decided by the user, and Scanner.nextInt() allways returns int. Even if this would work it would work only when T is int. But let's say that I'm okay if it just works when T is int.

Is there any way I can construct object of this class with such String, only when T is int. I doubt there is anything similar to class specialization like in C++.

Do you get what I want, let's say that string is "5 - 10". I want lower to be 5 and upper 10, and they need to be ints. Anyway possible.

Comment: If you only want ints, why have a generic type? Just make `lower` and `upper` both `int`.

Comment: Why do u want to use **generics**, when u have the specific type which is `int` ?

Comment: I have made this class for all types that extend Comparable, but I get that this constructor can only work when members are ints. If T's are floats then I would like to make special Range(String range) for that case.

Comment: What is the final objective of this class ?

Comment: To represent a range.... I also have a method boolean belongs(T value) which returns whether the value belongs in a range. I didn't post it because I didn't think it's important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this generically is to provide a `Function<String, ? extends T>` which allows you to parse a `String` to an instance of `T`.

```
public Range(String range, Function<String, ? extends T> parser){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(range);
    if(scanner.hasNext())
        this.lower = parser.apply(scanner.next());
    if(scanner.hasNext())
        this.upper = parser.apply(scanner.next());
}
```

---

Note that this overall approach isn't particularly good. For one thing, you can't create a range with only an upper bound; and for another, it limits you to input strings which are tokenized by `Scanner`; and you would be wise to make your fields `final`, in order to get the nice properties that gives you.

You are much better off doing the parsing outside the `Range` class (or, at least, outside the constructor). For example, you can use `Optional<T>` (or maybe `null`, shudder) to represent each of the bounds, and then declare your constructor like so:

```
public Range(Optional<? extends T> lower, Optional<? extends T> upper)
```

so you can create the range you want, using whatever format to provide the bounds you want - you construct the `lower` and `upper` instances before calling the constructor, so you're free to construct those how you like.